# I want my date format to be in the form 09:54:24

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller

```
public function spTimeOnline(ServiceProvider $provider)
    {
        $serviceProviders = DB::select('select sp.fname,sp.lname,sp.location,sp.area, sp.phone_number,sp.profile_picture, (select count(*) from trips where driver_id = sp.id and ended is not null) as totalTrips,(select count(*) from trips where driver_id = sp.id and ended >= CURRENT_DATE ()) as tripsToday,(SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,connected,disconnected)) from s_p_socket_connections where driver_id=sp.id) as time_spent,(SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,connected,disconnected)) from s_p_socket_connections where driver_id=sp.id and connected >= CURRENT_DATE ()) as time_spent_today ,(select
    case
        when isnull(connected)
        then false
        when isnull(disconnected)
        then true
        else false
    end
from s_p_socket_connections where driver_id=sp.id order by connected desc limit 1) as online from service_providers sp order by time_spent_today desc');

        return view('time_online', compact('serviceProviders'));
    }
```

And this is my blade file.

```
<td>{{$provider->time_spent ? \Carbon\CarbonInterval::second($provider->time_spent)->cascade()->forHumans(true):0}}</td>
```

it gives me the result in the format 9h 54m 24s but i want it in 09:54:24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[gmdate()](https://www.php.net/gmdate)** function :

```
{{ gmdate("H:i:s", 7140) }}
// 01:59:00
```

In your code, you can do like follow :

```
{{ $provider->time_spent ? gmdate('H:i:s', $provider->time_spent) : 0 }}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but this is the error i had.   ` "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (420) at position 0 (4): Unexpected character (View: /home/legacy/Desktop/projects/farassi/farassi-api/resources/views/time_online.blade.php) " `

Comment: can you tell me what is the outout of `$provider->time_spent` ?

Comment: This is the output 9h 54m 24s. But i want the output in the form 09:54:24

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked the way i wanted using gmdat() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>{{$provider->time_spent ? \Carbon\CarbonInterval::second($provider->time_spent)->cascade()->format('H:i:s'):0}}</td>
```

Comment: It did not work please. It only printed out H:i:s in the browser